# Python accessing Nested JSON Data and saving into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to generate a data structure from the following JSON

JSON Data

```
[{"ITEM0":"DescItem0","0":{"ITEM0":"DescItem0","ITEM1":"DescItem1","ITEM2":"DescItem2","ITEM3":"DescItem3"},"1":{"ITEM0":"DescItem0","ITEM1":"DescItem1","ITEM2":"DescItem2","ITEM3":"DescItem3"},"2":{"ITEM0":"DescItem0","ITEM1":"DescItem1","ITEM2":"DescItem2","ITEM3":"DescItem3"},"3":{"ITEM0":"DescItem0","ITEM1":"DescItem1","ITEM2":"DescItem2","ITEM3":"DescItem3"}},{"ITEM0":"DescItem0","0":{"ITEM0":"DescItem0","ITEM1":"DescItem1","ITEM2":"DescItem2","ITEM3":"DescItem3"},"1":{"ITEM0":"DescItem0","ITEM1":"DescItem1","ITEM2":"DescItem2","ITEM3":"DescItem3"},"2":{"ITEM0":"DescItem0","ITEM1":"DescItem1","ITEM2":"DescItem2","ITEM3":"DescItem3"},"3":{"ITEM0":"DescItem0","ITEM1":"DescItem1","ITEM2":"DescItem2","ITEM3":"DescItem3"}},{"ITEM0":"DescItem0","0":{"ITEM0":"DescItem0","ITEM1":"DescItem1","ITEM2":"DescItem2","ITEM3":"DescItem3"},"1":{"ITEM0":"DescItem0","ITEM1":"DescItem1","ITEM2":"DescItem2","ITEM3":"DescItem3"},"2":{"ITEM0":"DescItem0","ITEM1":"DescItem1","ITEM2":"DescItem2","ITEM3":"DescItem3"},"3":{"ITEM0":"DescItem0","ITEM1":"DescItem1","ITEM2":"DescItem2","ITEM3":"DescItem3"}}]
```

structure I need in dataframe
[image]

I run this code to normalize the input, but it creates a lot of columns

```
import json
import pandas

with open('.../TestNested.json') as f:
    j1 = json.load(f)
    
Data = pandas.DataFrame(j1)
DataNor = pandas.json_normalize(j1)
DataNor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Based on the sample, the `list` of `dicts` is not properly formatted to use `pd.json_normalize` to produce the desired dataframe.
- See the inline notation
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to rename any columns as needed

```py
import pandas as pd

# beginning with j1
j1 = [{'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', '0': {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}, '1': {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}, '2': {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}, '3': {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}}, {'ITEM0': 'DescItem1', '0': {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}, '1': {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}, '2': {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}, '3': {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}}, {'ITEM0': 'DescItem2', '0': {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}, '1': {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}, '2': {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}, '3': {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}}]

# convert j1 into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(j1)

# display(df)
       ITEM0                                                                                         0                                                                                         1                                                                                         2                                                                                         3
0  DescItem0  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}
1  DescItem1  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}
2  DescItem2  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}

# stack the columns of dicts into a single column
# rename column 'ITEM0' to 'ITEM', so there won't be a conflict with 'ITEM0' from inside the dict
dfs = df.set_index('ITEM0').stack().reset_index().drop(columns='level_1').rename(columns={'ITEM0': 'ITEM'})

# display(dfs)
         ITEM                                                                                         0
0   DescItem0  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}
1   DescItem0  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}
2   DescItem0  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}
3   DescItem0  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}
4   DescItem1  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}
5   DescItem1  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}
6   DescItem1  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}
7   DescItem1  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}
8   DescItem2  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}
9   DescItem2  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}
10  DescItem2  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}
11  DescItem2  {'ITEM0': 'DescItem0', 'ITEM1': 'DescItem1', 'ITEM2': 'DescItem2', 'ITEM3': 'DescItem3'}

# expand the dicts into separate columns and rows, and join them to dfs.ITEM
dfe = dfs.drop(columns=[0]).join(pd.DataFrame(dfs[0].tolist()))

# display(dfe)
         ITEM      ITEM0      ITEM1      ITEM2      ITEM3
0   DescItem0  DescItem0  DescItem1  DescItem2  DescItem3
1   DescItem0  DescItem0  DescItem1  DescItem2  DescItem3
2   DescItem0  DescItem0  DescItem1  DescItem2  DescItem3
3   DescItem0  DescItem0  DescItem1  DescItem2  DescItem3
4   DescItem1  DescItem0  DescItem1  DescItem2  DescItem3
5   DescItem1  DescItem0  DescItem1  DescItem2  DescItem3
6   DescItem1  DescItem0  DescItem1  DescItem2  DescItem3
7   DescItem1  DescItem0  DescItem1  DescItem2  DescItem3
8   DescItem2  DescItem0  DescItem1  DescItem2  DescItem3
9   DescItem2  DescItem0  DescItem1  DescItem2  DescItem3
10  DescItem2  DescItem0  DescItem1  DescItem2  DescItem3
11  DescItem2  DescItem0  DescItem1  DescItem2  DescItem3
```

Comment: @Cristian You're welcome. Glad this works for you.